# Have your everyday run

Tags: word-usage

I want to put an add for my property on a sharing website.
Is my sentence ok :

**You can have your everyday run on X Bridge.**

This bridge is very popular in my city and many people are going there for a run or cycling.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your sentence, but you might want to mention the distance from X Bridge if it is a selling point.

Comment: It might be clearer to say "You can have your **daily** run on [the Bridge], which is [only x miles/kilometres] away.  And ... and many people **go** there **to run or cycle**.

Answer (score 1):

While nothing is technically wrong, I think the meaning of "everyday" is a little unclear(ambiguous) here. Besides meaning "daily," this could also mean "common", "expected", or "standard." "**Daily**" is more clear in this case.

I think the use of "have" when referring to a "run" is a little misleading also, since you typically **go for** a run.

This accomplishes what you are trying to say with a little more clarity:

> *You can go for a daily run on X Bridge*

Comment: So do you think this sentence is correct :  If you are into having a healthy life, you can go for a daily run on X bridge.

Comment: @Mike - sounds great to me!